# Home Icon is not showing next to Hamburger icon in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I am using AppCompat library for DrawerLayout. However the action bar is not showing the launcher icon next to hamburger menu icon. I have tried several ways to resolve this issue but none of them worked. Anybody has a clue how to resolve it?

I want to show an image just like here Google+ icon is visible next to hamburger icon.

[image]

Best Regards

Comment: Here's an article by WilliamJ. Francis which illustrates that behaviour: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/the-android-uis-back-button-vs-up-button-demystified/ The burger icon is shown **in place** of the up icon, when it's already "up". Then, the burger icon is shown to open the navigation drawer.

Comment: Also note that the latest `appcompat-v7` is adhering to Material Design guidelines, which stipulate that there is no more app icon.

Comment: Thanks commonsWare. I spent 4 hours trying several ways to make the icon appear on actionBar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason appIcon/launcher icon is not appearing in the actionBar is because of the new design  guidelines of Material Design (Thanks to CommonsWare for telling). However I have used a much simpler & easier solution - Custom ActionBar.

Steps:

1. Create an XML file which follows your design pattern for Action Bar
2. In Activity:

   ```
   LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
   inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar, null);

   getSupportActionBar().setHomeEnabled(true); // for burger icon
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // burger icon related
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); // CRUCIAL - for displaying your custom actionbar

   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true); // false for hiding the title from actoinBar
   ```

Hopefully this will save some ones time.